# Unable to Create Excel Output File in Bash

Tags: csv, awk, export-to-csv

I have a bash script where I try to create an excel file with certain column names. When I run the script, this line stops the script and it doesn't go any further:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ OFS=","; print "Name,Email Address,User Name, Access Key,Date Created,Last Used,Days Old,AWS Account,AWS Account Number"}; NR > 1{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9;}' > "$aws_user_name"-aws-access-keys.csv
```

Why is this line holding up the script? All it does is create an empty file with no contents:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 tdunphy tdunphy 0 Sep  5 15:24 tdunphy-aws-access-keys.xlsx
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: You didn't specify a filename to read from, so it's waiting for data on stdin

Comment: And you are creating a CSV file not an .xlsx file (the format is different)

Comment: Ok. I just want to create a file with column headers for the CSV file. The content for those columnns are being created later in the scipt. If I read from the text file I'm creating and then create the CSV, the column headers will appear at the bottom of the content. This is what I am trying to avoid.

How do I just create the CSV file in bash with the column names I want?

Comment: If you are just wanting to write the headers out and nothing else, at this point in the script, then `awk` is WAY overboard. Just use `echo`. Replace that entire `awk` line with:  `echo "Name,Email Address,User Name, Access Key,Date Created,Last Used,Days Old,AWS Account,AWS Account Number" > "$aws_user_name"-aws-access-keys.csv`  Then later on you can append to that same file with whatever command fills that file `some_command >> "$aws_user_name"-aws-access-keys.csv` (notice the double arrows to *append* to the existing file)

Comment: Ugh. Much better to use `{ create_header; write_contents; } >out.csv` so you open it only once, rather than closing the file after the header and opening it again for contents. `>>` (like anything else that calls `open()`) isn't free -- every time you use it you're doing a directory lookup to get an inode, opening a file, etc; if what you open is a FIFO, then the intermediate close can significantly change semantics vs. just opening it once and keeping it open.

Comment: Charles Duffy. Ok I think I follow. So what you are saying to create two functions called create_header and write_header. And then output both of those to a CSV file only one time.

However all of this is happening inside one function of a larger bash script. Can I have a function within a function? Please confirm if I am understanding you correctly. Thanks!

Comment: I wasn't strictly telling you to run a function -- your `create_header` could be an `echo` command, and your `write_contents` could be an `awk` command... but yes, you *can* call a function from a function, so there's nothing wrong with the approach.

Comment: ...the real issue *is* that your `awk` is waiting for input on stdin, and nothing in your code provides it. Where that input comes from isn't really something we can help with with only the minimal content you've provided -- we don't know where the input *should* come from.

Comment: Ok gotcha. Thank you for the clarification. I think I can take it from here. I will let you know if I have any more questions. Thanks again for the advice!